# Windows Explorer Context Menu

Tags: c++, contextmenu, explorer

I want to add a context menu entry with C++. I've been searching but all I can find is some jackass trying to sell me some BS program that does it for me which is not what I am looking for. I'm not looking for anything that uses .NET or Visual C++ either. I want the straight C++ way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A decent tutorial, ignore the jackass title, is [available here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx).  This kind of shell programming requires COM, no escaping that.  Trying to write COM code without MSVC support classes is character-building.  But possible, as long as you know COM really well.

Comment: I tried it out but perhaps you could enlighten me to something: I added the DLL on Windows 7 and it didn't work but I added it on XP and it worked like a charm. Could you make a guess as to what my problem is?

Answer (score 5):

You can add a right-click menu item that just runs a program, simply by registry editing. No need to do shell extension for that. E.g. I used to have an extract icon thing (copy to clipboard),

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\copyIcon\=Copy icon to clipboard
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\copyIcon\command="path to the program" %1
```

Cheers & hth.,